# Shnayim Ushmonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty-two?

### ?שנים ושמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 282.

I think this number is unfavorable to lazy gematria.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty-one entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ה' צבאות (Lord of Hosts) appears 250 times in the Bible.
ה' אלוקי צבאות (Lord, God of Hosts) appears 14 times in the Bible.
אלקים צבאות (God of Hosts) appears 12 times in the Bible.
Hashem's name in some form described by הצבאות appears 4 times.
Hashem's name in some form described by צבאותינו appears 2 times.

Which makes **282** times Hashem is referred to in relationship to being Hashem of Tvaot.  (these are the total number of times this appears in the Tanach!)

Comment: +1. Impressive! But are you sure of your figures? Searching gets me the following: ה' צב-אות appears 260 times (okay, in some of those the name YKVK has the vowels and pronunciation of Elokim). ה' הצב-אות appears 1 time. אלקי צב-אות appears 15 times. אלקי הצב-אות appears 3 times. אלקים צב-אות appears 6 times. Total: 285. (The two times with בצבאותינו aren't actually references to Hashem's Name; they mean "with our armies.")

Comment: I found the number on the internet, not sure of the sources, so I went to the concordance and counted it up!

Comment: Hashem Tzevoas appears 259 times in Tanach. Hashem Elokai Tzevoas appears 15 times in Tanach. Elokim Tzevoas appears 6 times in Tanach. Your numbers just do not add up!

Answer (score 5):

According to Rashi's chronology (commentary to Jud. 11:26), the Ammonites waited 282 years from when the Jews conquered their (former) territory (from Sichon and Og) until they began laying claim to this territory and oppressing the Jews of Transjordania to force them to return it.

(In his message to the king of Ammon, of which the above verse is a part, Yiftach says that 300 years have elapsed since the conquest. Rashi takes this as an exact figure. Since at that point the oppression had lasted 18 years (ibid. 10:8), that leaves 282 years until it started.)

Answer (score 3):

http://archive.jta.org/article/1943/03/23/2860258/282-american-professors-submit-petition-to-roosevelt-on-nazi-massacres-of-jews

282 American Professors Submit Petition to Roosevelt on Nazi Massacres of Jews